# How to change only the content area of jsp without reloading the page completely in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, tiles

I have searched for a way to get around this situation but could not find one.

Currently I'm using Tiles View Resolver and have set menu bar on the left and a header common for all pages. Now I want the content to be loaded to content area (the remaining portion), without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Have you heard of ajax? Please google and find out what it does.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.... actually i need to load a page which is configured in tiles to my content area so that header and menu bar are not reloaded each time... If there is any other configuration better than Tiles i am ready to adopt that also ...

Comment: use ajax.it it better than adopting another configuration.

Comment: Thank you  Sanjay & false9striker.. ajax works for me..